# OpenGL/GLUT issue on OSX Sierra

Tags: macos, opengl, glut, macos-sierra

When I'm trying to compile this program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glGetError();
    exit(1);
}
```

with

```
cc -std=c99 main.c -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -framework Cocoa
```

on Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.1 with LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1), I get a segmentation fault:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xc0a7d, 0x00007fffd7ecea07 libGL.dylib`glGetError + 13, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
frame #0: 0x00007fffd7ecea07 libGL.dylib`glGetError + 13
```

I'm completely lost as to what is going on here. I can only assume it is some sort of linking issue. I don't have access to a pre-Sierra machine, but I had not encountered this issue before, so I assume something must have changed in Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not created an OpenGL context nor made it current. `glGetError()` is looking up the thread's current context and indexing into an internal function table to call the "real" implementation appropriate for that context. The lookup gets a null context address, so the access of the function table gets an access violation.

Comment: Judging by some other answers on SO, the behaviour of glGetError without a context might be platform dependent (or just not defined). But I think you're right, this is the right answer.